# Sqlalchemy Filter condition always returns True in subquery

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I made this statement using flask-sqlalchemy and I've chosen to keep it in its original form. `Post.query` is equivalent to `session.query(Post)`

I attempted to make a subquery that would filter out all posts in a database which are in the draft state and not made or modified by the current user. I made this query,

```
Post.query\
    .filter(sqlalchemy.and_(
        Post.post_status != Consts.PostStatuses["Draft"],
            sqlalchemy.or_(
                Post.modified_by_id == current_user.get_id(),
                Post.created_by_id == current_user.get_id()))
```

which created:

```
Where true AND ("Post".modified_by_id = :modified_by_id_1 OR  
"Post".created_by_id = :created_by_id_1)
```

Expected outcome:

```
Where "Post".post_status != "Draft" AND (
"Post".modified_by_id = :modified_by_id_1 OR  
"Post".created_by_id = :created_by_id_1)
```

I'm wondering, why this is happening? How can I increase the error level in SQLAlchemy? I think my project is silently failing and I would like to confirm my guess.

**Update:**

I used the wrong constants dictionary. One dictionary contains ints, the other contains strings (one for data base queries, one for printing).

```
_post_status = db.Column(
        db.SmallInteger,
        default=Consts.post_status["Draft"])
```

post_status contains integers, Consts.PostStatuses contains strings. In hind sight, really bad idea. I'm going to make a single dictionary that returns a tuple instead of two dictionaries.

```
@property
def post_status(self):
    return Consts.post_status.get(getattr(self, "_post_status", None))
```

Comment: What type are Post.post_status and Consts.PostStatuses["Draft"]? Is Post a model? SqlAlchemy builds the query based on type and python magic methods. I can tell you for certain if post_status is boolean and draft is empty string, sqlalchemy will generate an always true sql statement. There are surely other cases.

Comment: post_status is a small int and PostStatuses is an int (1 in this case).

Comment: can you be more precise?  Add a `print type(Post.post_status), type(Const.PostStatuses["Draft"])` right before you run your query.  it should print something like `<class 'sqlalchemy.orm.attributes.InstrumentedAttribute'> int`

Comment: Not sure how you expected to get `"Post".post_status != "Draft"` if both sides are int types. I have to assume you have a mis-typed comparison which will evaluate to always true. Please follow deque's instructions and give us more info.

Comment: So `Type(Post.post_status)` is `<type 'property'>` and `Const.PostStatuses["Draft"]` is `<type 'str'>`. I forgot that I have two dictionaries for the status constants. One that contains strings and one that contains ints. I used the one that contains strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the problem is that your `post_status` property isn't acceptable for usage in an ORM level query, as this is a [python descriptor](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/descriptor.html) which at the class level by default returns itself:

```
from sqlalchemy import *
from sqlalchemy.orm import *
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

Base = declarative_base()

class A(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'a'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)

    _post_status = Column(String)

    @property
    def post_status(self):
        return self._post_status


print (A.post_status)
print (A.post_status != 5678)
```

output:

```
$ python test.py
<property object at 0x10165bd08>
True
```

the type of usage you're looking for seems like that of a [hybrid attribute](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/orm/extensions/hybrid.html), which is a SQLAlchemy-included extension to a "regular" python descriptor which produces class-level behavior that's compatible with core SQL expressions:

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.hybrid import hybrid_property

class A(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'a'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)

    _post_status = Column(String)

    @hybrid_property
    def post_status(self):
        return self._post_status

print (A.post_status)
print (A.post_status != 5678)
```

output:

```
$ python test.py
A._post_status
a._post_status != :_post_status_1
```

be sure to read the hybrid doc carefully including [how to establish the correct SQL expression behavior](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/orm/extensions/hybrid.html#defining-expression-behavior-distinct-from-attribute-behavior), descriptors that work both at the instance and class level  is a somewhat advanced Python technique.

Comment: I ended up just testing against `_post_status` rather then the property `post_status`. This sounds like the better solution.